# Can an employer mandate an EUA-approved vaccine?

Tags: united-states, medical, employment, fda

Liberal political commentator Matt Yglesias just tweeted [this](https://twitter.com/mattyglesias/status/1365994052295020552?s=21):

> I’m not an expert in Vaccine Law.
>
> But the military requires a lot of vaccinations but says it can’t require the Covid vaccines because they are authorized under EUA and not the normal FDA process.

Now I’m not sure if the US military is subject to additional rules that the private sector is not in this regard.  But regardless, my question is, is it legal in the United States for employers  to mandate a vaccine which has FDA Emergency Use Authorization but not full FDA approval?

Comment: Interesting question. I know some US employers are purporting to mandate current COVID vaccine, particularly operators of long-term care facilities. I have not read of any legal challenges to such requirements. Given US employment-at-will doctrine, there may be few restrictions on what employers can mandate.